# How to align a button in a LinearLayout in Android app?

Tags: android, android-xml

I am a beginner and trying to create a calculator.

I am unable to align 3 button in single `LinearLayout` .

My code for the calculator.xml for the LinearLayout is.

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnOne"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.32"
        android:layout_width="107dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:text="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPlus"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.24"
        android:layout_width="107dp"
        android:text="+" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnEquals"
        android:layout_width="107dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.31"
        android:text="=" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

How i can bring the 3 buttons in a single row?

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:orientation="horizontal"` in the `LinearLayout` which contains the `Button`s.
Something like:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"     
    ..>

    <EditText>

    <LinearLayout
       android:orientation="horizontal" 
       ..>

          <Button .... />
          <Button .... />
          <Button .... />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `android:orientation="horizontal"` on an inner `LinearLayout` as other users say:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    ......>
<Button
    DockPanel.
    android:id="@+id/btnOne"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.32"
    android:layout_width="107dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:text="1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnPlus"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.24"
    android:layout_width="107dp"
    android:text="+" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnEquals"
    android:layout_width="107dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.31"
    android:text="=" />
</LinearLayout>
```

or you could try to insert your buttons inside a `StackPanel` with `Horizontal` orientation:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
<Button
    DockPanel.
    android:id="@+id/btnOne"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.32"
    android:layout_width="107dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:text="1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnPlus"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.24"
    android:layout_width="107dp"
    android:text="+" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnEquals"
    android:layout_width="107dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.31"
    android:text="=" />
</StackPanel>
```

I'm not trying code right now, so please, tell if this is a good solution for you.

You can also use `DockPanel`, or so. I suggest you to read any good tutorial about `Layouts` in android. That would help you a lot with comprehension of the layouts.

[Any layout tutorial (random)](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use a second LinearLayout inside the first one. Place it under the edittext. Set it's orientation to horizontal and place all your buttons in it. Set the buttons to fill parent. Change the weights of each button to 1. Now all three buttons will be the same size.

Answer (score 0):

Use an inner Linear layout to do this :

```
<LinearLayout
           android:orientation="horizontal" 
            ......>

          <Button .... />
          <Button .... />
          <Button .... />

</LinearLayout>
```